# I can't install R for Windows 10

Tags: r, installation, cran

I am unable to download the R ide to my laptop. I have tried the latest version on CRAN but It’s not downloading the executable file specifically the windows file. Requesting assistance on downloading and installing r on my laptop.

Comment: Hi Khadija, welcome to the stack! SO is a special kind of forum that's designed to answer specific questions, so we can't provide general assistance without specific details. Could you please provide more detail about the problem you are having?

Comment: Perhaps some of [these previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+%5Binstallation%5D+install+R+windows+-%22package%22) might help? If any of them solve your problem, be sure to mark this question as a *duplicate*.

Comment: The R ***IDE*** is not on CRAN, it's made by Posit (formerly RStudio). Have you tried downloading it from https://posit.co/download/rstudio-desktop/? (Do not confuse the R programming language and interpreter, "R", with the popular IDE named "RStudio". The latter is made to work with the former, but there is nothing inherent in RStudio that parses and evaluates any R code in the absence of the R interpreter.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.